# React: chunk file upload

Tags: reactjs

I am working on the functionality of file upload,
the catch in this is,
the file size ll be up to 5gb,
So I **looking for a package which provides chunk file upload**
Can someone suggest any package for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLUPLOAD, DROPDOWN JS is there if you want to upload large files in chunk.
I have used PLUPLOAD.
Note: implemented using simple js as react-plupload was throwing error

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the `npm` package @syncfusion/ej2-inputs, found from this link [here](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/uploader/chunk-upload/)

Comment: this package is not free @awarrier99

Comment: @Sumeet ah sorry I should've looked closer. From a Google search, here's a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/shiawuen/1534477) that might suit your needs but I don't know of any packages that can accomplish this